# Is there any way to find the index of everything found after using the count function

Tags: python-2.7

first question over here. I'm currently scanning through two lists and what I need to do is use the count function to find how many times a specific word appears and then I'd like to take the index of every one of those words and scan a second list for them. I have a list with a bunch of products and a second list with the corresponding prices so I'd like to be able to take the average of the prices and match them which each product. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not fully have understood your data structure, some code and data would be appreciated, but try:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2=['a', 'b','c', 'a', 'b']

b=list2.count('a')
print b
print

for i, j in enumerate(list2):
    if j == 'a':
        print i,": ", list1[i]
```

Result is:

> 2
>
> 0 :  1
>    3 :  4

Comment: This is essentially what I want, I can work off this :) Thanks a lot!